# vue.js is not showing in browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

1. 

TaskList.vue file code **Resoueces/assets/js/components**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task">
              </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return{
                tasks: []
            };
         },

         created(){
            axios.get('/tasks').then(response => (this.tasks = response.data));
         }
    };
</script>

2.App.js file code **Resources/assets/js**


/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('task-list', require('./components/TaskList.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});

3. welcome.blade.php file code
<body>

            <div id="app">

                <task-list></task-list>
            </div>
</body>
```

Error is describe in number like 1,2 its different error

```
 1) 

[Vue warn]: Property or method "task" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

2)`app.js:13797 GET http://localhost/tasks 404 (Not Found)`

```
3) You are running Vue in development mode.
    Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
    See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

4) app.js:13822 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (app.js:13822)
    at settle (app.js:35254)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:13696)
```

**Route List:** `route/web.php`

```
      Route::get('/tasks', function () {

    return Task::latest()->pluck('body');
});
Route::get('/tasks', function () {
    Task::ForceCreate(request(['body']));
});
```

Comment: It says that you did not declare the property or method "task", did you? can we see the code where you declare it and the template where you are using it?

Comment: I updated question -@CarlosSalazar

Comment: It is a app.js


require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('task-list', require('./components/TaskList.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

Comment: Welcome.blade.php file <body>

                <div id="app">
     
                    <task-list></task-list>
                </div>
</body>
    </html>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>

Comment: I voted to close this question as "Too broad" as you are showing 2 problems. Problem 1 is `app.js:13797 GET http://localhost/tasks 404 (Not Found)` and problem 2 is `app.js:36520 [Vue warn]: Property or method "task" is not defined` Try reducing your code to a small subset, so every problem gets attention, you don't risk partial answers where the answers basicly address half of your issue, and then you get into trouble with properly selecting an accepted answer

Comment: Please updated your question with all routes if you have any prefix of group also share where is this route in web.php or api.php ?

Comment: Is your route is in web.php or api.php ?

Comment: my route is in `web.php`. @C2486

Comment: Return json value from any controller instead from web.php directly its not json its collection, also I am not sure `Task` model is accessible or not ?

Comment: @C2486 now i got little bit... can we start chat discussion?

Comment: Sorry its 11:16 PM in india? But you can reach me via email.

Comment: oh@C2486 it ok. what should i do... i am following `laracast` video...

Comment: Yes make a controller and return json from there like ` retutrn response()->json([$task])`

Comment: app.js:13797 GET http://localhost/tasks 404 (Not Found) and problem 2 is app.js:36520 [Vue warn]: Property or method "task" is not defined. Yes you are right -@Ferrybig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see using the following to code

```html
   // no use "v for" error invalid syntax
<li v for="task in tasks" v-text="task">
              </li>
              
// you use code below
<li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task">
  {{task}}
</li>
 
------------------------------------------------
//see more about in vuejs
<tr v-for="(task,index) in tasks" v-text="task">
    <td>{{task}}</td>
    <td><span v-on:click="edit(index)">Edit</td>
    <td><span v-on:click="delete(index)">delete</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `-` here, thats why `task` is undefined for `v-text="task"`

```
  <li v for="task in tasks"
```

Use as doc suggests

```
    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task"></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I Updated this line axios.get('/tasks').then(function(response){this.tasks = response.data});
but its show me same error  -@Carlos Salazar

Comment: Did you changed `v for` to `v-for`?

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati Are you sure the same error is shown?  You error has 2 differend error messages, 1 404 error and 1 that `task` is not found. This error seems to address only the last error

Comment: @Kinnari : also share laravel routes

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    OrderStatusUpdated::dispatch();

    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/tasks', function () {

    return Task::latest()->pluck('body');
});

Comment: Please updated your question with all routes if you have any prefix of group also share where is this route in web.php or api.php ?

Comment: my route is in `web.php`

Comment: @C2486 can we start discussion chat>?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in this line

```
axios.get('/tasks').then(response => (this.tasks = response.data));
```

Vue states that if you're using `this` do not use arrows function because the `this` is lost in the scope. so try

```
axios.get('/tasks').then(function(response){this.tasks = response.data});
```

and see if the error is solved

Comment: You need arrow functions so this binds to the local data correctly when using vue